# Cast from generic type to unrelated type sub-class always fails

Tags: ios, swift, generics, casting

I have a class which is derived from generic type class.

```
open class Model<T>: BaseModel where T: SomeData {
}
```

There is another class derived from `SomeData`.

```
open class NetworkData: SomeData {
}
```

Now I have a class which serves as base class for many models.

```
open class ParentModel: Model<NetworkData> {
}
```

There are two child classes derived from ParentModel.

```
open class SonModel: ParentModel {
}

open class DaughterModel: ParentModel {
}
```

There many other classes derived from Model generic type.
In one of the situation I want to use this generic type as function argument and later type-cast it to specialize class.

I have done following code to achieve the purpose

```
func someName<T: SomeData>(model: Model<T>) {
    guard let model = model as? DaughterModel else {
        //Some code here
    }
    //Main logic goes here
}
```

However, on the line

```
guard let model = model as? DaughterModel
```

I am getting following error

> Cast from 'Model' to unrelated type 'DaughterModel' always fails.

How to fix the error? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It sounds like you should be using structs and protocols instead of classes here. That way you wouldn't be down casting at all. Down casting is generally not something you should be doing.

Comment: Thannks Fogmeister for the reply. It would be great if you could explain how protocol could solve the problem.

Comment: Can you show why you are using the classes and subclasses? What is inside them that needs the hierarchy? I could poss take a look at that.

Comment: @Fogmeister: It would not be possible for me to show the complete code. The base class SomeData contains identifier. Derived classes like SonModel and DaughterModel contains some extra property than ParentModel. I want to use a property from DaughterModel in the mentioned method.

Comment: This just looks like a diagnostics bug (it shouldn't give you a warning), which is fixed in Swift 4. So you can just ignore it.